# BottomSheetBehavior сам скрывается, но не полностью

Tags: android, material-design, android-spinner, android-bottomsheetbehavior

у меня есть активити в котором SurfaceView отоброжает Preview с камеры, и FAB по нажатии на которую выскакивает/задвигается BottomSheetBehavior в котором настройки для камеры, и AppCompatSpinner в котором эффекты для камеры, но когда я выбираю другой эффект для камеры bottomSheet сдвигается в низ в STATE_COLLAPSED хотя я сделал setSkipCollapsed(true), а в onStateChanged пишет что STATE=STATE_HIDDEN хотя это STATE_COLLAPSED. Сталкиваюсь с этой проблемой второй раз и всё ещё не могу исправить. надеюсь кто-то знает как решить эту проблему

Comment: скорей всего срабатывает cancel при появлении второго диалога когда выпадет Spinner. Его можно тоже переопределить

Comment: bottomsheet работает не через bottomsheetdialog

Comment: второй диалог и не появляется. т.к. Spinner единственный диалог в активити